# Why Math is an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, object, javascript-objects

I have started learning Javascript recently ,So sorry if my doubts seems not logical to you

I have seen the definition for an Math object , following is the code for it

```
interface Math {
    /** The mathematical constant e. This is Euler's number, the base of natural logarithms. */
    readonly E: number;
    /** The natural logarithm of 10. */
    readonly LN10: number;
    /** The natural logarithm of 2. */
    readonly LN2: number;
    /** The base-2 logarithm of e. */
    readonly LOG2E: number;
    /** The base-10 logarithm of e. */
    readonly LOG10E: number;
    /** Pi. This is the ratio of the circumference of a circle to its diameter. */
    readonly PI: number;
    /** The square root of 0.5, or, equivalently, one divided by the square root of 2. */
    readonly SQRT1_2: number;
    /** The square root of 2. */
    readonly SQRT2: number;
    /**
     * Returns the absolute value of a number (the value without regard to whether it is positive or negative).
     * For example, the absolute value of -5 is the same as the absolute value of 5.
     * @param x A numeric expression for which the absolute value is needed.
     */
    abs(x: number): number;
    /**
     * Returns the arc cosine (or inverse cosine) of a number.
     * @param x A numeric expression.
     */
    acos(x: number): number;
    /**
     * Returns the arcsine of a number.
     * @param x A numeric expression.
     */
    asin(x: number): number;
    /**
     * Returns the arctangent of a number.
     * @param x A numeric expression for which the arctangent is needed.
     */
    atan(x: number): number;
    /**
     * Returns the angle (in radians) from the X axis to a point.
     * @param y A numeric expression representing the cartesian y-coordinate.
     * @param x A numeric expression representing the cartesian x-coordinate.
     */
    atan2(y: number, x: number): number;
    /**
     * Returns the smallest integer greater than or equal to its numeric argument.
     * @param x A numeric expression.
     */
    ceil(x: number): number;
    /**
     * Returns the cosine of a number.
     * @param x A numeric expression that contains an angle measured in radians.
     */
    cos(x: number): number;
    /**
     * Returns e (the base of natural logarithms) raised to a power.
     * @param x A numeric expression representing the power of e.
     */
    exp(x: number): number;
    /**
     * Returns the greatest integer less than or equal to its numeric argument.
     * @param x A numeric expression.
     */
    floor(x: number): number;
    /**
     * Returns the natural logarithm (base e) of a number.
     * @param x A numeric expression.
     */
    log(x: number): number;
    /**
     * Returns the larger of a set of supplied numeric expressions.
     * @param values Numeric expressions to be evaluated.
     */
    max(...values: number[]): number;
    /**
     * Returns the smaller of a set of supplied numeric expressions.
     * @param values Numeric expressions to be evaluated.
     */
    min(...values: number[]): number;
    /**
     * Returns the value of a base expression taken to a specified power.
     * @param x The base value of the expression.
     * @param y The exponent value of the expression.
     */
    pow(x: number, y: number): number;
    /** Returns a pseudorandom number between 0 and 1. */
    random(): number;
    /**
     * Returns a supplied numeric expression rounded to the nearest integer.
     * @param x The value to be rounded to the nearest integer.
     */
    round(x: number): number;
    /**
     * Returns the sine of a number.
     * @param x A numeric expression that contains an angle measured in radians.
     */
    sin(x: number): number;
    /**
     * Returns the square root of a number.
     * @param x A numeric expression.
     */
    sqrt(x: number): number;
    /**
     * Returns the tangent of a number.
     * @param x A numeric expression that contains an angle measured in radians.
     */
    tan(x: number): number;
}
```

When I searched about it on google , I found it is written in TypeScript here the interface is used to define a structure of an object which is Math , but it seems to me same like a class declaration, So why do we call Math as an object ?

Comment: You cannot construct a Math instance, so it is not a "class".  (Also it long predates the existence of Typescript.)

Comment: You can conceptually think about it as a "namespace" object. In other languages the methods on math would be called "static methods." Read more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math

Comment: Can you specify the meaning of Namespace object ?

Comment: The idea of OOP is that everything is an object. And indeed, we access properties and call methods on `Math`. So why wouldn't it be an object?

Comment: "*I have seen the definition for an Math object*" - no. What you found is a TypeScript type declaration for the type interface that the `Math` object implements. There is no "definition" for the `Math` object since it is provided by the runtime, but you can conceptually think of it as `const Math = {PI: 3.1415926535…, abs(x) { return x < 0 ? -x : x }, …};`

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript `Math` is a [namespace object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math). When you call methods on `Math`, like `Math.abs(x)`, you are calling what's known as a [static method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static). Static methods are a common OO pattern for implementing classes that shouldn't be instantiated - most commonly, utility classes.

Comment: Can you specify the meaning of a namespace object ??

Comment: `Math` is not a class, so there is no distinction between instance methods and static methods. It simply would be an object method - or actually, it's just a plain function, which does not need to be called on the `Math` object as its receiver.

Comment: I am getting so confused , I had learnt that Object is an instance of the class is it not the only definition or it's definition changes on the basis of programming language ? If Object is an Instance of the class in Javascript , then Math object should have a Class right ?